# Java Script function does not work

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

```
var Structure[undefined]   
function run{
  Structure[0]
}

function setStructure(structure){
  Structure[0]=structure
}

setStructure(House);

function House(){
  //nothing
}
```

Why is the return of House() function not in Structure[0]?
It is for a Minecraft PE mod.

Comment: You never call `House`, you just pass it (i.e. the function) around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you intended this:

```
function run{
    Structure[0]() // <--- notice the parentheses.
}
```

Without the parentheses, the function `run` does not do anything. It just references the function, without invoking it.